# Extract specific items in list

Tags: python, list

I wanted to know how to extract the color Pink is the list given below, if there are many similar items...

```
board=[
         ['**Pink','Pink**','Yellow'],
         ['**Pink**','Orange','DarkBlue'],
         ['Teal','Purple','Gold']
       ]...
```

I would like to know exactly the position of second Pink, i.e second element of 1st nested list.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get positions of all 'Pink' entries in your list of lists as tuples, you can do it like this:

```
positions = [(i,j) for i in xrange(len(board)) 
             for j in xrange(len(board[i])) if board[i][j] == 'Pink']
```

This will give you:

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0)]
```

the positions of all the three 'Pink' entries